# 5.15.0-50-generic not booting and getting message "mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)"

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I have had Ubuntu 22.04 lts installed for some time now and suddenly this morning it would not boot. I get the message "mtd device must be supplied (device name is empty)" on the screen and it just get stuck there. The only thing I found online that would cause this problem would be a full disk, but that is not my case. I then went to access the grub menu and found that I have 2 options to boot from: "5.15.0-50-generic" and "5.15.0-48-generic" where if I choose the 48 version it then booted fine, but the 50 won't and I have no idea why. Does anyone knows the reason?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: Hi @karel. Not really. I know how to boot from this older version. I just don't know what could have happened to make newer version suddenly stop working like it did.

Comment: Report it as a bug: [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/q/5121/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I report a bug?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: Already a bug report. Fixed back in August. Is your system fully updated & current version? mtd device must be supplied
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1981622 & some work arounds. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2476796&page=3

Comment: tks. I will take a look at that. For now I just delete the .50 and I am using .48. At least now I just get the message, but the system boots fine.